# Service account to access SQL server from IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

My Asp.Net/C# web app hosted on IIS is using 2 different service accounts to access 2 DBs on 2 SQL servers on the network. IIS is running as service account1 coonnecting to DB1 on SQL server1.

I have the User ID, Password for account 2 configured in the web.config connectionstring expecting  this to supersede the IIS setting just for DB2 on SQL server2. This is not working. Is there a better way to handle this? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Which versions you are running at? Please post your web,config section!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, DB1 uses Windows Authentication and should be configured for that. Make sure, the connection string is configured to select "Integrated Security=true;" in its connection string. DB2 needs SQLServerAuthentication enabled. No impersonation will work for DB2 but a regular connection string will do:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

See also: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr1" connectionString="Data Source=SQL1;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="constr2" connectionString="Data Source=SQL2;User ID=user;Password=pwd;Initial Catalog=DB2;Integrated Security=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: what is the problem? did you check the auth log on your sql server?